# Is there a way to use Mac icns file in Windows expression blend projects

Tags: wpf, cross-platform, icons, expression-blend, ico

I have a set of icns files that I'd like to use is some cross platform UI can I use these icns files without converting them to png or ico?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no.  I have used this site to solve this problem:

http://iconverticons.com/